# Network tab of chrome dev tools: How to reset sorts?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

[image]I don't found how to reset the sort order of requests in the Network Tab...

The documentation says you have to right-click on the "waterfall" header, but the right click do nothing on my version ( 106.0.5249.119 )

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I finally understood what I hadn't understood !!
The sort symbol doesn't disappear, but I return to the initial sort

[image]